# How can I get the an element's order inside a group of seleted elements with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get an element's order inside a group of selected elemtns, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li id="example">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $('#example').click(function (e)) {
        $this = $(this);
        // some code
    });
</script>
```

I need to know the order of $this inside all li elements. For example, in this case the code should return 5.

My first thought is to traverse all the li elements and compare each element, but I think this approach is slow. I can also add a data-order attribute to each li element, but is there any other easier or faster way to do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/?

Comment: Actually your first idea is almost exactly what the solution is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 $('#example').click(function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $index = $('li').index($this);
   alert($index + 1) //+1 because index start from 0
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ueyDy/)

**note: this will select all the `<li>` in the document..to be specific you can give a class/id to `ul` and use class/id selector `$('.ulClass li').index($this);`**

Comment: thx, I think i got enough to go on.

Answer (score 1):

but this will return 4 since the count starts from 0.

```
 $('#example').on('click',function(e){
         $this = $(this);
        console.log($("li").index(this))
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szGtd/

Comment: Nice...but be aware that this is looking up all li's in your page. So the code will fail if there are other lists on the page.

Comment: Thanks! That can be solved by adding a class to the `<li>`

Comment: thx, I think i got enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ul` tags are all wrapped within a container, you can do:

```
var index = $('#container li').index($('#example')) + 1;
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DScxd/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#example").click(function () {
  var index = $('li').index(this);
  console.log(index + 1)
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pAuMG/